# Sending email attachment with java spring - error 400 for multipartfile

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I want to send my file through the email by angular's ng-file-upload and java spring (using multipart file).

I've got error 400:

> Cannot construct instance of org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types

My html button:

```
  <button type="button" ngf-select="uploadFiles($file)" ng-model="file" ngf-max-size="1MB" enctype="multipart/form-data">Select File</button>
```

And my angular controller:

```
$scope.uploadFiles = function(file) {
    $scope.file = file;
}   

$scope.emailData.file = $scope.file;
    $http.post("sendemail", $scope.emailData)
        .then(function (response) {         
            $scope.succes =  true;
        },
        function(fail) {
            $scope.error = true;
        });
```

I'm sending my file with another data's like title, description etc.

I declared Multipart file with getters/setters.

Then my Java Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/sendemail")
```

public class EmailSenderController {

```
@Autowired
EmailSender emailSender;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public EmailStatus sendEmail(@RequestBody EmailData emailData) {
    return emailSender.sendData(emailData);
}}
```

Finally i've got EmailSender java class.

```
     private EmailStatus sendM(EmailData emailData){
        MimeMessage mail = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
         MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mail, true);
         helper.setTo(to);
       // ANOTHER STUFF
         byte[] bytes;

      if(!emailData.getFile().isEmpty()) {
        bytes = emailData.getFile().getBytes();
        helper.addAttachment(emailData.getFile().getOriginalFilename(), new ByteArrayResource(bytes));
      }}
```

So, I think it's all good. My pom.xml has dependency:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I used this example: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/wiki/spring-mvc-example

Comment: Did you try `@RequestBody MultipartFile file` ? Or if you want file + some data: `@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestPart CustomObject customObject`

Comment: I will try it tomorrow, thanks ;) can someone tell me how MultiPart works? When ive got for example http post with data and File in one url /datas i can just put 2x MultiPart and that will just split my datas?